# Adding z-value attribute to lines

Tags: qgis, line, fields-attributes, z-value

I have a shapefile of 200 lines (all connected) with the coordinates x and y and a DEM raster. I would like to give the z value to the lines by taking it from the raster.

I have read several discussion on how to do the same operation with a points shapefile but I was wondering if would be possible to have the same results with lines. Maybe applying the z-value to a line vertex, or calculating the average elevation of the line length?

[image: example]

Comment: Have you tried `Drape (set z-value from raster)` tool?

Comment: Yes, but he does not add the extra column.

Comment: What kind of 'extra column' do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting an extra column with the altitude value: e.g.  [01] line, altitude 57meters.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Field Calculator to create a new elevation field, using a way similar to the point layer. The operation will give you a punctual information extract from the raster.

In the line layer's Attribute Table use the Field Calculator to create a new field (numeric, real) with this expression

```py
raster_value('DEM_NAME', 1, start_point($geometry))
+
raster_value('DEM_NAME', 1, end_point($geometry))/2
```

changing the value `DEM_NAME` with the name of your DEM.

This will create a new field with the average of the elevations calculated at the beginning and at the end of the line.

But if you want to calculate a more accurate average you can, still using the Field Calculator, use a more complex expression that calculates the elevation average recorded at *n* points along your line.

Considering that using the expression

```py
collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry)/10, 1),
line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element * 10)))
```

you can create a sequence of points along your line (as observable in the image below) starting from 0 to the end of the line, with 1 meter of distance

[image: example1]

you can extract from your raster the elevation of each of those points and calculate the average elevation of all them.

To do it, you can use the following expression:

```py
array_sum(
array_to_string(
array_foreach(
array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry)//10, 1),
line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element * 10)),
expression:=raster_value('DEM_NAME', 1, collect_geometries(@element))
),
delimiter:=' ,'))
/
array_length(
array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry) // 10, 1),
line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element * 10)))
```

The resultant data will be the sum of calculation of all the elevations in all of the points (calculated by `array_sum`) divided by the number of points (calculated by `array_length`).

This is the result:

[image: example2]

**ADDENDUM**: If you want a rounded number for your elevation just add `round(` at the beginning of the expression and close all the adding a `)` at the end of all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time ago. If you want to split your lines into segments of a given lenght and then calculate the slope of the segments:

[Calculate slope of line segments with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273440/calculate-slope-of-line-segments-with-qgis)